# Div is going behind fixed div when scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, position, css-position, fixed

I'm having a problem with the property position:fixed.
If you check out my 
[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AyLNL/) you see, that when you scroll, and the black div hits the top, then via JS it adds the style "stick" which makes it fixed in position - as intended. Unfortunately, when I do this, and the div is getting the fixed style, the div below the black bar jumps up a bit, which ruins the idea.

The main CSS I think you have to look at is:

```
.orangeContent {
max-width:960px;
width:100%;
margin:0px auto;
padding:40px 0px 0px 0px;}

    header {
max-width:1920px;
width:100%;
margin:0px auto;
padding:0px;
background:#ffffff;

.stick {
position:fixed;
top:0px;
box-shadow:0px 4px 2px -2px #b32f01 ;
transition-duration:0.2s;}
```

And of course the Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("header");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
        }
    });
});
```

So, basically, any idea on how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the black header jumps out of the box flow, so the div below jumps up. I suggest you add the class fix to the pageWrapper instead of the header itself and then, in your css:

```
.pageWrapper header{
    position: static
}

.pageWrapper div { /* the one with all the lorem ipsum */
    padding-top: 0;
}

.pageWrapper.stick header{
    position: fixed
}

.pageWrapper.stick div { /* the one with all the lorem ipsum */
    padding-top: 20px; /* needs to be set as the same height of the header */
}
```

I edited your fiddle to show you what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/AyLNL/3/

I used the .stick + .text selector which basically means the .text after the .stick, but I suggest you place the .text inside the pageWrapper and then go with .stick .text

Answer (score 0):

Of course div will jump as `position:fixed` takes element from the flow. If your header has static height than adjust padding(or margin) of `header.stick + div` in your css file otherwise recalculate it on adding/removing `'stick'` class